# How to perform operations over arrays in a pandas dataframe efficiently?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I've got a pandas DataFrame that contains NumPy arrays in some columns:

```py
import numpy as np, pandas as pd

data = {'col1': [np.array([1, 2]), np.array([3, 4])],
        'col2': [np.array([5, 6]), np.array([7, 8])],
        'col3': [9, 10]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I need to store a large frame like this one in a CSV file, but the arrays have to be strings that look like this:

```py
col1,col2,col3
"(1, 2)","(5, 6)",9
"(3, 4)","(7, 8)",10
```

What I'm currently doing to achieve this result is to iterate over each column and each row of the DataFrame, but my solution doesn't seem efficient.

This is my current solution:

```py
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
array_columns = [column for column in df.columns if isinstance(df[column].iloc[0], np.ndarray)]

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for column in array_columns:
        # Here 'tuple' is only used to replace brackets for parenthesis
        df[column][index] = str(tuple(row[column]))
```

I tried using apply, although I've heard it's usually not an efficient alternative:

```py
def array_to_str(array):
    return str(tuple(array))

df[array_columns] = df[array_columns].apply(array_to_str)
```

But my arrays become `NaN`:

```py
   col1  col2  col3
0   NaN   NaN     9
1   NaN   NaN    10
```

I tried other similar solutions, but the error:

```py
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

appeared quite often.

Is there a more efficient way of performing the same operation? My real dataframes can contain many columns and thousands of rows.

Comment: csv is text-based and should not be used for nested data structure. Why do you need csv? can you store the data in binary, e.g. `df.to_pickle`?

Comment: A requirement is to match the output format of the data people can get from a particular webpage/archive that belongs to a branch of the company that I work for. This format with quotes and parenthesis has been used for years and won't be changed.

Comment: `df[column][index] = scalar` should never be used. use `df.at[column, index] = scalar`... also, please don't do: `pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None` those warnings are good warnings for a reason.

Comment: In any case, nothing you do is going to be particularly efficient, having numpy.ndarray objects inside dataframes is not what pandas was designed to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
tupcols = ['col1', 'col2']
df[tupcols] = df[tupcols].apply(lambda col: col.apply(tuple)).astype('str')
df.to_csv()
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to convert the arrays into `tuple` for the correct representation. In order to do so, you can apply `tuple` function on columns with `object` dtype.

```
to_save = df.apply(lambda x: x.map(lambda y: tuple(y)) if x.dtype=='object' else x)

to_save.to_csv(index=False)
```

Output:

```
col1,col2,col3
"(1, 2)","(5, 6)",9
"(3, 4)","(7, 8)",10
```

**Note**: This would be dangerous if you have other columns, e.g. string type.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {'col1': [np.array([1, 2]), np.array([3, 4])],
        'col2': [np.array([5, 6]), np.array([7, 8])],
        'col3': [9, 10]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df[['col1', 'col2']] = df[['col1', 'col2']].applymap(lambda x: tuple(x))
df[['col1', 'col2']] = df[['col1', 'col2']].applymap(lambda x: ''' "{}" '''.format(x))

         col1        col2  col3
0   "(1, 2)"    "(5, 6)"      9
1   "(3, 4)"    "(7, 8)"     10
```